# CSS @media directive not working on mobile browser

Tags: css

I am trying to hide certain columns on a table in small devices such as mobiles to make a responsive page. It works fine on my desktop with Chrome and Firefox but as soon as I try even a simple example like below on my Android mobile (using Chrome) all the columns appear even though my screen is much smaller than 800. I can't see anything obvious why it's not working. Any pointers?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media(max-width: 800px) {
    th.nomobile, td.nomobile{
        display:none;
        width:0;
        height:0;
        opacity:0;
        visibility: collapse;
    }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table cellpadding="7" cellspacing="1" class="border" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <th><strong>Col1</strong></th>
  <th class="nomobile" style="width: 75px;"><strong>Col2</strong></th>
  <th class="nomobile" style="width: 75px;"><strong>Col3</strong></th>
  <th style="width: 225px;"><strong>Col4</strong></th>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What phone do you have?

Comment: I have a android moto g

Comment: Play around with the size it has happen with me on newsletter too on my galaxy 3 it still shows up as regular

Comment: I have tried it on Safari as well as Chrome and I get the same result

Comment: I cracked it I think. You need this:     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing the `viewport` meta tag in your html's header, start with a simple `viewport` meta tag like below and customize it based on your needs:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;">
```

Find more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

If you don't include the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

your media query will see the actual pixels of the screen (720x1280) instead of css/display pixels (360x640). In landscape this would make the difference in trigger or not triggering the query.